# Grails basics:dates, strings, and object properties

Tags: grails

I'm just starting out with Grails, transitioning from Javascript

In a controller, I'm trying to do this below, but I get an error

```
def list = {
  def projects = Project.list()

  projects.each {
    it.dateCreated = it.dateCreated.format('mm/dd')
    println it.dateCreated
  }
  return [projectInstanceList: projects, 
          projectInstanceTotal: projects.size()]
}
```

In my view I then display the dateCreated for a project, I just want to format the date so it's cleaner/more concise.

This is my error:

```
'java.lang.String' to class 'java.util.Date'
```

I also tried assigning this to `it.dateCreated`

```
new Date(2011, 09, 31, 10, 57, 00)
```

But that gave a similar error also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should **never change** a domain instance property like that just for "display" purposes. The reason for that is the domain instance is actually going to be persisted with your changes when the hibernate session flushes.

Second, let the view display the property in the correct format. That's the responsibility of the view, not the domain instance, or the controller.

Comment: so in the view how would I manipulate this string ${project.dateCreated}? Javascript?

Comment: depends on how you are displaying it. You shouldn't be manipulating it just formatting the output. For instance you could just do ${project.dateCreated.format('mm/dd')} if you were iterating a list of projects (and the variable of the current project was called project). You might want to investigate the Grails documentation for various ways to format things using tags.

Answer (score 1):

`Date.format(...)` returns a String ([see the documentation](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Date.html#format%28java.lang.String%29)).  You can't assign a java.lang.String to java.util.Date

Either `println it.dateCreated.format('mm/dd')` or use [Grails' formatDate tag](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/formatDate.html) to render this in your view.

Answer (score 0):

`it.dateCreated` is a `java.util.Date`. When you do: `it.dateCreated.format('mm/dd')` you are formatting the date but returning a `java.lang.String`. Then you try to assign that `String` to your `it.dateCreated`, but it can't take it, because it is a date.

Try just: `println it.dateCreated.format('mm/dd')`